# Do crash 'popup' windows show when SAS is running in batch?

Tags: sas

I have a program I want to run in batch.  When running it interactively the code occasionally crashes (still working on figuring out why) and when it does this a popup window shows with the typical memory exception messages.

My question is - If I run the program in batch, will this popup still show? If it does it would prevent the execution of the next jobs until someone closes the window which I want to avoid.

The crash is intermittent and I don't want to break our nightly run by just making the change and seeing what happens.  Alternatively, does anyone have code I can use that's guaranteed to cause a crash so that I can test it?

My environment is SAS V9 TS1M2 running on XP Pro.

Comment: FYI, it's possible this is more of a SuperUser question than a StackOverflow question, depending on where you end up going with it (and if I understand SU's purpose correctly); ie, the parts about running programs in the scheduler.

Comment: Thanks Joe - yeah I thought about that but I figured I was more likely to get a helpful response here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running in batch mode but running in an interactive Windows session (ie, not running via the scheduler on an account that's not logged in currently), then yes, you will see the popups when SAS.EXE crashes.  It will be just like any other program crashing (ie, nothing particularly SAS specific).

If it's running on a 'nightly run' then you should be able to run it non-interactively, in which case it should not affect anything subsequent; this depends on the specifics of how you've set up the scheduler.  I would normally schedule each SAS job as a separate process and then set them up as dependent on success of the prior run.  You certainly should be able to run a specific process just to test your changes that could be scheduled to run after all of the 'critical' (production) runs.